# How can I get the result of a promise in node & jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to NodeJS and Jade/PUG so I know this can be a really simple question for many of you but for me I can't understeand any of the answers a get from the internet because the term 'Promise' and how it works is a little "confusing" for me.
I am querying a postgre database to get several values from a table (really simple query). If I do this without using a promise everything works fine, console prints the result and everyone is happy, but when I try to store this result into a variable and pass it as a parameter to a Jade template things change.

I have read that, in order to do that, I need to use promises because it is more likely that when the variable is being accessed, the value might not be resolved yet and that's what Promises are for. So here I have my code:

**hero.js**:

```
getHeroes: function()
{
    //Initialize array
    var elem = [];
    console.log('Querying heroes');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {

        pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) 
        {
            if (err) 
            {
                return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err)
            }
            //Execute SELECT query
            client.query('SELECT name from heroe;', function (err, rows, result) 
            {
                //Iterate over results
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.rowCount; i++) 
                {
                    //PUSH result into arrays
                    elem.push(rows.rows[i].name);
                }
                done()
                if (err) 
                {
                    return console.error('error happened during query', err)
                }
                resolve(elem)
            })
        });

    })

}
```

And this the part of my server.js where I call that function:

```
app.get('/jade', (request, response) => {
var heroList = [];
heroList = hero.getHeroes();
console.log(heroList);
response.render('test_jade', {param1: 'test'});
})
```

that console.log shows up "Promise { pending }" and I don't know how to "listen to the resolved event and retrieve the value from it once it has finished".

Would appreciate any advice/solution or even a good Node.js manual where all this mess is explained for total newbies like me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not how you use promise.
Try this,

```
app.get('/jade', (request, response) => {
    var heroList = [];
    hero.getHeroes().then(data=>{
        heroList = data;
        console.log(heroList);
        response.render('test_jade', {param1: 'test'});
    }).catch(e=>{
        //handle error case here when your promise fails
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

You should also `catch` in case your promise fails.

Comment: Damn it! That's what I was looking for, that ".then(" is the "tell me when the promise is resolved and do this" I was talking about in my question. Thanks a lot for the fast answer anuragasaurus. Let me ask you something about this approach if you don't mind. If I wait for the Promise to resolve and then I load the Jade view, am I violating the "Asynchronous spirit" of NodeJS?

Comment: @Ejher Yeah, what's your doubt?

Comment: I pressed intro before finishing the question so maybe you didn't see the full text :P. Here it is: "If I wait for the Promise to resolve and then I load the Jade view, am I violating the "Asynchronous spirit" of NodeJS?"

Comment: @Ejher If you need data from database to show in the template, then you will have to wait for the promise to resolve and then render the view using this data. But in the code above you are not using the data returned, so you dont need to wait for promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @anuragasaurus . You really saved a lot of time to me. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ejher Glad, it helped :)